# How to implement Likes, like in Instagram?

Tags: java, android

I want to implement the `post liking` system within my code.

My database looks like:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe0eT.png)

Once the user clicks the like button, their UID should be stored in the database as such..

**individual_row.xml**

[xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XH2y.png)

**recycler.java**

```
public class recycler extends AppCompatActivity{
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference myref;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        myref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("famuid");
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
                Blog.class,
                R.layout.individual_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                myref
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
                viewHolder.setCaption(model.getCaption());
                viewHolder.setImage(model.getImage());

            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }}
```

**Blog.java**

```
public class Blog {
    private String name,image,caption;
    public Blog() {
    }

    public Blog(String name, String image, String caption) {
        this.name = name;
        this.caption = caption;
        this.image = image;
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCaption() {
        return caption;
    }
    public void setCaption(String caption) {
        this.caption = caption;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

**BlogViewHolder.java**

```
public class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
   View mView;
   TextView textView_title;
   TextView textView_decription;
   ImageView imageView,likes;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    DatabaseReference databaseref;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    String uid;
   public BlogViewHolder(final View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       mView = itemView;
       textView_title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
       textView_decription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
       imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.postimg1);
       likes = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
       // set click event
       likes.setOnClickListener(this);}
    // onClick Listener for view
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        if (v.getId() == likes.getId()){
            likes.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),uid,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ITEM PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
   public void setName(String name) {
       textView_title.setText(name);
   }
    public void setCaption(String caption) {
       textView_decription.setText(caption);
   }
   public void setImage(String image) {
       String c = "none";
       if (image.equals(c))
       {
           imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
       else {
           BlogViewHolder.getBitmap loadBitmap = new BlogViewHolder.getBitmap();
           loadBitmap.execute(image);
       }
   }
    public class getBitmap extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bit = null;
            if (params.length == 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("You should pass me a url!!");
            final String src = params[0];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(src);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bit;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            if (bitmap !=null){
                imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postimg1);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I implemented an `onclick` function on likes (imageview) to change it from a `white heart` to `red heart` but how do I store their `uid` to display the no. of likes on each post?

Comment: What database type do you use?

Comment: @dh19 I am using firebase database